# Вывод числа с заданой точностью

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Помогите решить вопрос. Задание стоит что нужно  вывести к примеру число 800 в таком формате как 800.00 
DATABASE  ORACLE 10G
Как это сделать, попытки реализовать через `ROUND`,`TRUNC` безуспешны
По типу:

```
SELECT ROUND(800,2) FROM DUAL;
SELECT TRUNC(800,2) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`round` и `trunc` - это функции округления, они изменяют число, но не оказывают никакого влияния на его отображение. Чтобы вывести число на экран в нужном формате, нужно использовать функцию для форматирования - `to_char`:

```
select to_char(800, '999D00') from dual
```

Полный список опций форматирования смотрите тут: [Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210)

Comment: Наверное, лучше `'990D00'`...

Comment: @Akina Да, пожалуй. А еще больше мне нравится `FM990D00`.

Comment: Обычно такая хотелка как форматирование в строку на сервере делается для того, чтобы помещать полученный литерал непосредственно в форму, где рассчитано количество знакомест (моноширинный шрифт), или для позиционного CSV. В этом случае FM не очень к месту...

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо `TO_NUMBER` или `TO_CHAR`

Исходная таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (q1 varchar2(32))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (q1)
         VALUES ('3020')
    INTO Table1 (q1)
         VALUES ('123.44')
    INTO Table1 (q1)
         VALUES ('-34.00')
    INTO Table1 (q1)
         VALUES ('+34.00')
    INTO Table1 (q1)
         VALUES ('aaa')
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Q1, '9,999.99') 
  FROM table1
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(q1, '^[+-]?[.0-9]+$')
;
```

Результат:

```
TO_CHAR(Q1,'9,999.99')
3,020.00
123.44
-34.00
34.00
```